# Change image button position when background imageview zoomed

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas

I have image view in my activity, on that image view, another image button was set on particular xy pixel(120x,320y). When i zoom my background image view, that image button have to set in 120x, 320y pixels. I am facing this issue, how to solve this. Please help.

I have tried this

```
Matrix matrix = floorImageView.getImageMatrix();
float currentZoom = floorImageView.getCurrentZoom();
float[] pts = {0, 0};
matrix.mapPoints(pts);
float newTagX = (x * currentZoom) + pts[0];
float newTagY = (y * currentZoom) + pts[1];
userLocationIB.setX(newTagX);
userLocationIB.setY(newTagY);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything till now?

Comment: Yes I have tried, please check edit my question

Comment: Hi any one please help me.

Comment: Your ImageButton's initial position is 120, 320, and you want to re- position it to newTagX, newTagY on zooming in ImageView, correct? Can you post a screenshot of initial and final positions you want? I am unable to get it.